# Run Primewire NPM Dependency

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to run and execute this code. https://github.com/Evan-Goode/primewire?files=1
I'm not familiar with JavaScript. I know you have to call if from an html file but I'm not sure if I have to point to where it is located. I installed the npm library and have the node_modules folder but I'm not sure how to run and execute this code to get the result. If anyone could help explain this to me it would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

```
var primewire = require('primewire');

function display(err, links, id) {
 if (err) {
    return console.error(err.stack);
}

console.log('%d total links found for "%s".', links.length, id);
console.log('Watch now at ' + links[0]);
}

primewire({
title: 'The Simpsons',
year: 1989,
season: 1,
episode: 2
}, display);

// Using an ID instead of title/year will result in less page load time.
primewire({
id: '4131', // http://www.primewire.ag/watch-4131-The-Simpsons
season: 1,
episode: 4
}, display);

primewire({
title: 'Saw',
year: 2004
}, display);

primewire({
id: '1672' // http://www.primewire.ag/watch-1672-Saw-II
}, display);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask here. You question is very off topic like it is written now. You likely will have a hard time running node.js without any JS knowledge. The package does not run from HTML

Comment: Put your code please... We need to check your code

Comment: @AralRoca there is no code that is the issue

Comment: you need to include this line to use it: `var primewire = require('primewire');`

Comment: i included my code, this is the index file, i also have a test.js, example.js, bin.js package.json

Comment: you are using node? or is javascript in client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have linked to a repository containing an NPM module.

As the `README` in the project states, you can install the module to your current working project by running:

```
npm install primewire
```

which would then allow you to add it as a dependency to your project:

```
var primewire = require('primewire');
```

You typically never run code from your `node_modules` folder, but rather treat it as a dependency consumed in your project through `require` or static linking. (Modeling functionality from the documentation in the repo)

That said, they appear to provide you some examples, so you could `clone` the repo and just run `node` against them.

It sounds like you might benefit from taking pause and [learning some NodeJS fundamentals, like the typical workflow](http://nodeguide.com/beginner.html).

Comment: Oh ok. So j have a script that's I run for my website. Could I integrate this into the script?

Comment: Yes, after installing, simply `require` the module to start using it.